# Why molten lithium burns through the glass but sodium not?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equipment, glass

It's well-known in laboratory practice that one shouldn't melt lithium in a glass equipment and there isn't such rule about other alkali metals.
You may damage the glass with sodium but lithium will make a hole in your flask.

So, why does this rule only hold for lithium?

Comment: ...  I definitely recall that one of methods of preaparation of buthyllithium includes melting of lithium in boiling dodecan. I even participated in making of one bunch using this method. Worked like a charm with no problems.